# “have played golf”?

Tags: tense, present-perfect

- I have played golf for many years.
  (*have played* indicates an action continuing into the present.)

For example : I have played golf for many years. I can win this game very easily.

Speaking about this sentence, can we say “**have played**” indicates an action completed at the present time?

For example : I have played golf for many years. (Until now) But I'm old now. I'm giving up golf.

Can you give some examples like this?

Comment: The present perfect can be used for both, past things that are finished or past things that influence the present. Do you know about that? If your question is, "which is meant here," the answer is always "one sentence alone might not be enough to tell, you need the context."

Comment: In your second example, **have played** indicates that the speaker still sees themself as a player who is _about to_ give up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you have the right idea:

"I played golf for many years.  Gave it up in 2013."

"I've played golf for many years.  Think it's time to lay down my clubs."

(Also: "I've been playing golf for decades.  Maybe I've had enough?")